# Number of rules (Data Mining)

Tags: combinatorics, machine-learning, data-mining

This is a paraphrasing of a statement from  *Data Mining* by Witten et al., 4th edition, on section 1.6.

Consider the set $S = \{1, \dots, 288\}$.

A **rule** is defined as a one-element singleton set whose element is from $S$, e.g., $\{1\}$, $\{2\}$, etc..

**The question**: how many sets with no more than $14$ rules can be created?

**My work**: There are $288$ such rules. The result should then be given by 
$$\sum_{i=1}^{14}\binom{288}{i} \sim 2.36 \times 10^{23}\text{.}$$

See [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+(288+choose+i),+i+%3D+1+to+14) for the computation.

**The correct answer**: Witten et al. states that the answer is $\sim 2.7 \times 10^{34}$ with no explanation of the derivation.

Hopefully my terminology is correct. If someone knows this material well and I have something incorrect in my problem setup, please let me know.

**Further context which might be helpful**: this statement arises from looking at a data set of weather variables. We have five variables per observation, for which each variable has $4$, $4$, $3$, $3$, and $2$ variables. Thus, there are $4 \times 4 \times 3 \times 3 \times 2 = 288$ possibilities for each rule, according to Witten et al. It is possible for a variable to not participate in a rule, but every rule must have at least one variable.

> If we restrict the rule set to contain no more than $14$ rules [based
>   on a previous example], there are around $2.7 \times 10^{34}$ possible
>   different rule sets.

The following slides were taken from [www.cse.unt.edu/~nielsen/classes/CSCE5380/Slides/Chapter1.pptx](http://www.cse.unt.edu/~nielsen/classes/CSCE5380/Slides/Chapter1.pptx):

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: He appears to have calculated $288^{14} \sim 2.7\times 10^{34}$. There are 288 possible rules, so he's calculated the number of sequences of length 14 whose elements are rules.

Comment: @AlbertSteppi So then, the correct answer for the question posed would be $\sum_{i=1}^{14}288^{i}$?

Comment: @AlbertSteppi I would also imagine that there are redundancies which are supposed to removed as well... as $\{1, 2\}$ should be the same as $\{2, 1\}$, for example.

Comment: I think your original answer is correct by my interpretation of rule sets. Witten seems to mean something different by this term. I don't think this calculation is important to the material in the text so I think it's safe to ignore it.

Comment: @AlbertSteppi Thank you!